# matlab save create directory if doesn't exist

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, char, save

I am trying to write a MATLAB function that extends the "save" command to create the specified path if it doesn't already exist.  I have been successful with a single variable, but not with multiple variables.  With multiple variables, I receive the following error message:

```
31                  variables_to_save(i) = variable_name;
Conversion to cell from char is not possible.

Error in saveMatVars (line 31)
            variables_to_save(i) = variable_name;
```

Here is my function:

```
function saveMatVars( file_path, varargin )
%saveMatVars saves variables in varargin to file specified in file_path, creating the file path if it doesn't exist
%   varargin is the variables to save

% get path and filename from file_path
[parent_folder, ~] = fileparts(file_path);

% if parent_folder doesn't exist, create it
if ~exist(parent_folder, 'dir')
    mkdir(parent_folder);
end

% get names of variables to save
num_vars = length(varargin);
switch num_vars
    case 0
        return
    case 1
        variable_name = inputname(2);
        variable_name = matlab.lang.makeValidName(variable_name);
        variable_val = varargin{1};           
        feval(@()assignin('caller', variable_name, variable_val)); % create
 a dummy function so I can access the current function's workspace
        variables_to_save = variable_name;
    otherwise % note - this part does not work
        variables_to_save = cell(1,1);
        for i = 1:num_vars
            variable_name = inputname(i+1);
            variable_name = matlab.lang.makeValidName(variable_name);
            variable_val = varargin{i};
            feval(@()assignin('caller', variable_name, variable_val)); % create a dummy function so I can access the current function's workspace
            variables_to_save(i) = variable_name;
        end
        variables_to_save = string(variables_to_save);
end
% save variables_to_save in file_path
save(file_path, variables_to_save);
return
end
```

The documentation on "save" says the following about the variables to save:

```
save(filename,variables) saves only the variables or fields of a structure array specified by variables.
```

I have tried various functions for converting char arrays to strings and to cell arrays to no avail.

Comment: Try: variables_to_save{i} = variable_name;

Comment: I'm not really understanding the purpose of the majority of this. Why not just pass `file_path` and `varargin` back to `save` after you create the directory? That way you can just use the exact same syntax as `save` and let it handle the error checking for you.

Comment: Because since saveMatVars is a function, it doesn't have access to the variables in its caller's workspace.  I have to re-create the variables in saveMatVar's workspace.  "Save" must be a script...  perhaps saveMatVars should be a script as well.